# Web Scraping Error: Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, web-scraping

#### Summarize the problem

I am trying to practice a simple example from [Keith Galli tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjKQ6V_ViQE&t=925s), and scraping some headers from [target web](https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/example.html). But I don't know why Keith can scrap successfully from his tutorial but I can't. Now I am working at company, if I replace this url by "company website", it works. I don't know if it is a proxy issue or some else.
The code is like this:

```
# Load the webpage content
r = requests.get("https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/example.html")

# Convert to a beautiful soup object
soup = bs(r.content)

# Print out our html
print(soup.prettify())
```

And my prompt is:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='keithgalli.github.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /web-scraping/example.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026C42D80190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Thanks~

Answer (score -1):

The link is to the example.html is fine. Either you don't have an internet connection or some network security policy is blocking your connection to the example.html.

Comment: Now I am working at company, if I replace this url by "company website", it works. I don't know if it is a proxy issue or some else.

Comment: Yes it probably is your network policy blocking access.

Comment: Pls, do you know how to close the proxy or blocking? Thanks.